# How fast can I drive a stepper motor?

Tags: stepper

I have a 28BYJ 48, 5V stepper motor. After some trial and error I got it working with the all the sample examples in Arduino IDE.

However when I increase the speed of the motor using setSpeed() beyond 15, the motor stopped rotating. Following is the configuration in which I am running the motor.

```
const int stepsPerRevolution = 2048; 
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);
myStepper.setSpeed(15);
```

I wanted to understand what factors limit the speed. And how fast can I rotate this motor?

Thanks,

Manish

Comment: Read about chopping drivers.  There are many answered questions on EESE, no need for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

*"I wanted to understand what factors limit the speed. And how fast can I rotate this motor?"*
Read through the data sheet for your motor-the answers are there. Each different motor has its own data sheet. This will require some work on your part to find the data sheet and the info from it you require. Which can be used to deduce the answer your question.

Comment: While the data sheet will give you the inductance the actual speed limitation of a given motor is determined not by the motor but by the driver's available voltage, which must be many times the nominal motor voltage.  Often all you really need to know about the motor is rated current, or steady state voltage from which it can be calculated.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah-youre right- it would depend on the circuit controlling the motor too. So youre's sayin the speed limitation does not strongly depend on the information in the data sheet. .

Comment: The inductance may the used as a parameter to a chopping software-if the motor is chopping driven